# Page load vs html content load via Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

What are the issues/points to consider in the question page load vs html content load via ajax? The most of web sites has the same structure: header with menu, main content and footer. So, it looks very reasonable/sensible to load only the container with main content, not the complete page. But as I see this approach is not widely used. The main navigation remains implemented in "old style"-method (via `a href`). What is here important to think about?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of mobile users and such without JavaScript support, people running older browsers, browser history, search engine spiders etc. - there's plenty of reasons to use traditional navigation.

Answer (score 2):

Well I think this differs per person. I personally don't like using javascript if it isn't needed. While others do. There are some tools that fix most of the problems with javascript like hash links aka:

yoursite.com/#/path/to/object

That make it possible to use the back and forward key and send the links to your friends. Also using javascript does ease a bit on your bandwidth and pages load faster.

But you have to give up on google since google bot can't parse javascript sites. So for front end pages you are better off using normal HTML and for backend admin stuff you can use javascript to make your gui more user friendly and neat.

Answer (score 1):

A few reasons:

- running two requests when one would be enough is wasteful
- search engine friendlyness
- increasing popularity of script blockers
- caching
- old browsers with incompatible javascript engines
- accessibility
- server-side code is easier to debug than ajax

Answer (score 0):

Think about bookmarks, google bot, sending links to pages.

Other then that AJAX navigation is perfectly fine.

Comment: Grrr.  Why do we seem to keep having this same conversation?  Bookmarks and back-buttons and sending links are three of the many ways to name the same problem: having state represented in the URL.  And they have the same answer: anchor tags.  Works fine.  Google Bot crawls AJAX-based sites perfectly well;  see http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/ .  Google Corp has its problems but a critical shortage of smart people is not among them.

Comment: I am not saying these problems are impossible to overcome :-) But this is definitely some extra work :-)

Answer (score -1):

Cost (having to build it twice (or sacrifice non-JS users like search engines), breaking bookmarking, breaking back/forward, breaking sending a link to a friend. (These 'breaking' things can be worked around, but it is more work and still imperfect).

Vs benefit: Potential minor (since you are still loading the majority of the page) performance increase.

Comment: No matter what you do, optimizing for SEO is always additional work and it's no harder for AJAX-based ones than for template-based ones.

Comment: Yes it is - you have to build the server side version and the client side version, and then you have to do everything else you would do for SEO anyway.